How was Boltzmann able to neglect the possibility of an infinite number of microstates for a given macrostate?
Classically, since momentum, and position are continuous variables, it is possible for a given macrostate to posses an infinite number of microstates. But I understand that this issue is resolved by quantum mechanics, (explained very nicely here).
But Boltzmann's time was before quantum mechanics, so when deriving his equation for entropy:
$$S = k_B \ln{\Omega}$$
how was he able to neglect the possibility of infinite microstates for a given macrostate?

If all macrostates would have infinite number of microstates, then you wouldn't be able to distinguish between any pair of macrostates. This would effectively mean that there are no different macrostates for any system, just a unitary ("perfectly chaotic") state which would render Boltzmann law obsolete.

I'm confused, just because there are an infinite number of possible microstates for a given microstate, why does this mean that the macrostates become indistinguishable.

Because then all macrostates would have same infinite entropy, as per Boltzmann law $S=k_B \ln \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is number of microstates.

But my question is "how was Boltzmann able to justify this, when deriving that very equation", so this just seems like circular reasoning to me

Probably Boltzmann knew calculus. I am not sure whether he used special functions or an equivalent limiting procedure, but one could count all the microstates with energy $E$ for an ideal gas as
$$
\Omega = \int_V dx_1...dx_N\int dp_1...dp_N\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{p_i^2}{2m}-E\right)
$$
(which is just the partition function of the microcanonical ensemble.) The calculation includes infinite number of microstates (via continuous integration), but the result is finite and leads to Sackur-Tetrode equation.
The problem here is not the infinite number of microstates, but that the result is dimensional, hence valid only up to an arbitrary dimensional multiplicative constant (which means an additive constant in entropy) - which is the problem that inserting $2\pi\hbar$ in quantum mechanic really solves:
$$
\int dxdp\longrightarrow \int  \frac{dxdp}{2\pi\hbar}.$$

So you are saying that just because momentum and position are continuous, this does not mean that there is an infinite number of microstates for a given macrostate? Intuitively this makes little sense to me.

@cookiecainsy this is not what this answer says... quite the opposite, in fact.
